# How to move characters to certain points

Tags: c#-4.0, encryption

I have a problem in which I have to `SWAP` or `move` characters and integers. Like I have any characters `A` . now I have some cases, like

*NOTE:- Have to use characters `A-Z` and integers `0-9`*

1. `A`, now I want that when my program run I assign some integer value to this character, If I assign value 3 to this character then `A` will become `D` or it just move to 3 places.
2. Now if I have a character like `Y` and I add 4 then it will become `C` means after `Z` it will again start from character `A`.
3. Same condition I have to follow with Integer if i have 9 and we assign 3 to it then it will become 2 because loop start from 0 not from 1. Means we have to use only 0-9 integers.

I know that i am using wrong name to question but i have no idea that what lines i have to use for that kind of question.

Hope you understand my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your input a string? Give a complete example.

Comment: yes input is a string value like `AB` now i have integer value like `12` now i move `A` to `1` point and `B` to `2` points, So that it will become `BD`..

Comment: Integer value `12`? What if your input string is `"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"`? Integers cannot have that many digits. Also, what if the string is `"AAB"` and the "shift value" is `11`? What happens to the B?

Comment: For reference: [Ceasar Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

Comment: @Jon Sir if our input string will be more than 2 albhabets then we will substring it and will take only it's first two alphabets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below extension method, which does the following:

1. It creates 2 dictionaries in order to speed up the key look up in the `alphabet`
2. Will parse the `inputString` variable, split it in substrings of the length of the `moveString` variable's length (or the remainder)
3. On every substring, it will evaluate each character in order to detect if it's a digit
4. If it's not a digit, it looks up for the value in the `swappedAlphabet` dictionary, by using the `int` key
5. If it's a digit, it applies a modulo operation on the sum of the digit and the corresponding `moveint` value
6. It finally aggregates all the characters in the final result string

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string
            alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        string inputString = "ABC123D", moveString = "12";
        var result = inputString.Swap(alphabet, moveString);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}

static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Dictionary<TValue, TKey>
        SwapKeysValues<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> input)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<TValue, TKey>();
        input.ToList().ForEach((keyValuePair) =>
        {
            result.Add(keyValuePair.Value, keyValuePair.Key);
        });
        return result;
    }

    public static string Swap(
        this string input,
        string alphabet,
        string move)
    {
        Dictionary<char, int> 
            alphabetDictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
        {
            alphabetDictionary.Add(alphabet[i], i);
        }

        var swapedAlphabet = alphabetDictionary.SwapKeysValues();
        return Enumerable
            .Range(0, (int)Math.Ceiling(input.Length / (move.Length * 1M)))
            .ToList()
            .Aggregate<int, string>("", (s, i) =>
            {
                var l = i * move.Length + move.Length;
                var cInput = input.Substring(i * move.Length, 
                    (l > input.Length) 
                        ? input.Length - i * move.Length : move.Length);
                return s + cInput
            .Select((c, index) =>
            {
                int intCandidate;
                if (!Int32.TryParse(c.ToString(), out intCandidate))
                {
                    var length = (alphabetDictionary[c] +
                        Int32.Parse(move[index].ToString()));
                    return
                        swapedAlphabet[(alphabet.Length > length)
                            ? length : length % alphabet.Length];
                }
                else
                {
                    var moveInt = Int32.Parse(move[index].ToString());
                    return Char.Parse(((intCandidate + moveInt) % 10)
                        .ToString());
                }
            })
            .Aggregate<char, string>("", (a, b) => a + b);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: it works fine for alphabets but how to implement this logic for `integer` case.

Comment: dear sry to say but your logic is not working properly if i enter `input=xz`, `move=23` then it retur's `BC` that is wrong it should return `ZC` and in the case of integer if i `input=48` and `move=23` then it should return `61` but it's returning me `1`,,so plz solve it..thanks..

Comment: Fixed. I've merged all the logic under one method. Please try it now.

Comment: it shows me refreence error `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<char,int>' does not contain a definition for 'SwapKeysValues' and no extension method 'SwapKeysValues' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<char,int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

Comment: Have you added the `ExtensionMethods.SwapKeysValues` method?

Comment: i have just folllow your logic ,i think i haven't added but how to add it.i just use SwapKeysValues method that is created by you.

Comment: ok i solve first problem related to reference one i haven't use statis class.but after solving that problem i have an another error that is `The given key was not present in the dictionary.`...

Comment: here i am getting error ` var length = (alphabetDictionary[c] +
                            Int32.Parse(move[index].ToString()));` error is `The given key was not present in the dictionary`...

Comment: Sure, let me know if you need some other tweaking :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple way to implement a [Caesar Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) with the restrictions you defined.

```
var shift = 3;
var input = "HELLO WORLD 678";

var classAlphabets = new Dictionary<UnicodeCategory, string>
{
    { UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator, " " },
    { UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" },
    { UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber, "0123456789" }
};

var encoded = input.ToUpperInvariant()
                   .Select(c => new { Alphabet = classAlphabets[Char.GetUnicodeCategory(c)], Character = c })
                   .Select(x => new { x.Alphabet, Index = x.Alphabet.IndexOf(x.Character) })
                   .Select(x => new { x.Alphabet, Index = x.Index + shift })
                   .Select(x => new { x.Alphabet, Index = x.Index % x.Alphabet.Length })
                   .Select(x => x.Alphabet.ElementAt(x.Index))
                   .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (builder, character) => builder.Append(character))
                   .ToString();

Console.Write(encoded);

// encoded = "KHOOR ZRUOG 901"
```

Decoding is simply a case of inverting the shift.

Comment: I understand that your code moves from z to 0, isn't it? You should account for two different "alphabet" variables, one for letters and the other one for numbers.

Comment: @varocarbas as I said this is a starting point. The OP appears to be asking people to write his code for him without making any effort to solve it himself or even understand the problem. I don't think it's in the spirit of StackOverflow for us to do that. If he has any more specific questions about how to achieve the final part I'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: @MattDavey I do agree with you completely. Actually I started to answer this question because was pretty straightforward (char into ints), then I started to account for the A-Z and 0-9 parts and spent more time than I should. The reason for my comment is that your approach does not account for the basic idea (A-Z vs. 0-9); didn't say anything about the exact code and how well meets the requirements of the OP.

Comment: @varocarbas you're right, `z` would be transformed to `2` given a positive shift of 3. I had thought about having a dictionary of alphabets keyed by unicode category eg. `Dictionary<UnicodeCategory, string> = { UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter, "ABC...XYZ" }, { UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumer, "0123456789" }`. I think that might work but I'm not inclined to spend much more time on this question to try it out :). Anyway I'll chuck you an upvote for your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have upvoted you back because of your "DO YOUR CODE YOURSELF" claim :)

Comment: @varocarbas I did get a version going which wraps letters/numbers separately and also preserves spaces (see edit), just as a proof of concept. Seems to work ok! It would look a lot nicer in a language which had first class tuple support though.

Comment: I think it looks nice enough anyway, basically your are defining a string with all the elements (4 different strings in this case) and analysing the given 1-length substring. I intended to avoid that by relying on the in-built char/int (all the chars are already stored in C# in the expected order), although this has the disadvantage of not including the functionalities of a dictionary. My approach is better from the efficiency point of view, and yours from the speed and easy of coding ones. For a so small number of target characters I do think that your approach is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative you have is relying on the in-built `character`/`integer` types which follow the order you want; with an additional consideration: if you account for caps, it would deliver caps ("B" after "A" and "b" after "a"). The only thing you need to worry about is making sure that the iterations will be limited to the A-Z/0-9 boundaries. Sample code:

```
public string moveChar(string inputChar, int noPos)
{
    string outChar = checkBoundaries(inputChar, noPos);

    if (outChar == "")
    {
        outChar = basicConversion(inputChar, noPos);
    }

    return outChar;
}

public string basicConversion(string inputChar, int noPos)
{
    return Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar(inputChar)) + noPos));
}

public string checkBoundaries(string inputChar, int noPos)
{
    string outString = "";

    int count1 = 0;
    do
    {
        count1 = count1 + 1;
        string curTemp = basicConversion(inputChar, 1);
        if (inputChar.ToLower() == "z" || curTemp.ToLower() == "z")
        {
            if (inputChar.ToLower() != "z")
            {
                noPos = noPos - count1;
            }

            inputChar = "a";
            outString = "a";
            if (inputChar == "Z" || curTemp == "Z")
            {
                inputChar = "A";
                outString = "A";
            }

            count1 = 1;
        }
        else if (inputChar == "9" || curTemp == "9")
        {
            if (inputChar != "9")
            {
                noPos = noPos - count1;
            }

            inputChar = "0";
            outString = "0";

            count1 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            inputChar = curTemp;
            outString = inputChar;
        }
    } while (count1 < noPos);

    return outString;
}
```

It expects strings (just one character (letter or number) per call) and you can call it simply by using: `moveChar("current letter or number", no_of_pos_to_move)`. This version accounts just for "positive"/"forwards" movements but it might easily be edited to account for the inverse situation.

Answer (score 0):

Caesar cipher can be easier like this:

```
static char Encrypt(char ch, int code)
{
    if (!char.IsLetter(ch))
    {
        return ch;
    }
    char offset = char.IsUpper(ch) ? 'A' : 'a';
    return (char)(((ch + code - offset) % 26) + offset);
}

static string Encrypt(string input, int code)
{
    return new string(input.ToCharArray().Select(ch => Encrypt(ch, code)).ToArray());
}

static string Decrypt(string input, int code)
{
    return Encrypt(input, 26 - code);
}

const string TestCase = "Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.";

static void Main()
{
    string str = TestCase;

    Console.WriteLine(str);
    str = Encrypt(str, 5);
    Console.WriteLine("Encrypted: {0}", str);
    str = Decrypt(str, 5);
    Console.WriteLine("Decrypted: {0}", str);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```